# Fundamental group and path-connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p:E \rightarrow B$ be a covering space, $E$ and $B$ are path-connected. Let $A$ be a path-connected subset of $B$
. How to use fundamental group to give a sufficient and necessary condition to make $p^{-1}(A)$ be path-connected?

Comment: If $A$ is a point, then this happens if and only if $p$ is a homeomorphism. Do you want to impose more conditions on $A$?

Comment: No,when $A$ is a point, $p^{-1}(A)$ is a set of several points, since $p$ is a covering map. What I want is to use fundamental group as a tool.

Answer (score 1):

The book [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) deals with Covering Spaces in Chapter 10, using covering morphisms of groupoids. Section 10.7 is on pullbacks of covering maps, and 10.7.6 gives a Mayer-Vietoris type sequence involving fundamental groups and sets of path components. Then Corollary 1 implies with your notation  that if $a \in A, y \in E  $ satisfy $p(y) =a$, and $i: A \to X$ is the inclusion, then the components of $D= p^{-1}(A)$  are bijective with the double cosets of the subgroups $i_*\pi_1(A,a)$ and $p_*\pi_1(E,y)$ of $\pi_1(B,a)$. So $p^{-1}(A)$ is path connected if and only there is only one double coset.